# Software Installation in Linux

Tags: linux, installation

I am a beginner to Linux. I tried to install a program via console. It may take much time if I ask to software owners and I think problem is with my Linux knowledge. The steps were

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Until this point everything seems to be OK. But when I type `make install` subsequently, it gives error as,

```
[100%] Built target gmsh
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebInfo"
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/gmsh
Cmake Error at cmake_install.cmake:36 (FILE):
    file INSTALL cannot copy file " /home/orxan/build/gmsh" to "/usr/local/bin/gmsh".

make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Comment: try `sudo make`

Comment: Do you have permission to write to /usr/local/ ? `sudo make install` will probably do the trick.

Comment: Off-topic here. I suggest asking on [unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @perreal,wildplasser: that solved problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
cannot copy file " /home/orxan/build/gmsh" to "/usr/local/bin/gmsh"
```

In this case, you will need sudo privileges to write to `/usr/local/bin`, as it's owned by `root`.

```
sudo make install
```

Actually, this is the case for most software installations. `make` itself doesn't require these privileges, but installing almost exclusively does. You can theoretically `chown` the `/usr/local/bin` directory to be owned by you, but this could cause unforeseen problems.

Comment: Often, you can `make install DESTDIR=/tmp/softinst/` without being root, then copy recursively it, e.g. `sudo cp -v -R -p /tmp/softinst/. /.`